# What does the "Bonus" mean when selecting an act in which to do bounties?

Tags: diablo-iii

I've noticed that two of the acts have a "bonus" when doing bounties, and the other three do not. I don't know if it's always two, or how the acts with a bonus are selected.

What does this bonus mean? How are those acts chosen?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Acts having the "bonus" tag should reward bounties with double blood shards.

These acts are chosen randomly, and change once a day.